# JavaScript Objects as argument to functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am a little confused about the way JavaScript treats objects passed as arguments to functions.

For example, in the following code:

```js
var a = {
  val: "old"
};
var b = {
  val: "old"
};

function update(a, b) {
  a.val = "new";
  b = {
    val: "new"
  };
}

update(a, b);

console.log(a, b);
```

The output comes as:

[image]

The `val` property of `a` is changed but that of `b` is not. I read somewhere that Objects are passed by reference to functions. Can anyone please explain this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make this

```
function update(a, b) {
  a.val = "new";
  b = {
    val: "new"
  };
}
```

you are pointing b to a new object, but only in the update function

Comment: thanks. that cleared the confusion

Answer (score 0):

In the `a` case you are changing the object that variable `a` points to. In the `b` case you are creating a new object and making `b` points to this new object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the object references are passed by value to the function, 
And that is why when you changed the property of a it reflected.
But as you assigned a new object to b, b inside the function got referenced to the new object.